# VSCode: How to navigate between .proto files and the generated Go code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am to trying to find references in a monorepo for an rpc function defined a protobuf file.

I have .proto files that are used to generate go code using `protoc`. Is there a way to navigate from message definition in protobuf file to the message struct in `.pb.go` file? For example

helloworld.proto

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

helloworld.pb.go generates the go structs

```golang
type HelloRequest struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
}

type HelloReply struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Message string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=message,proto3" json:"message,omitempty"`
}
```

helloworld_grpc.pb.go generates the rpc server and client interfaces

```golang
type GreeterServer interface {
    SayHello(context.Context, *HelloRequest) (*HelloReply, error)
    mustEmbedUnimplementedGreeterServer()
}

type GreeterClient interface {
    SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *HelloRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*HelloReply, error)
}
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to navigate from messages to structs in the go files or from rpcs to server or client interfaces in the go files (so I can then navigate to the implementations of those interfaces).